# Additional Azure Resource Mananger Templates for Visual Studio 2022

Tags: azure, visual-studio, templates, azure-resource-manager

I've just created a new, blank "Azure Resource Group" - Project in Visual Studio 2022.
Is there any option to add additional resources to this list (see image below)? Like an Application Gateway or a Network Security Group? Found neither any extensions nor packages.

And why is it still working on a schema version 2015?
(https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json)

[image]

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any option to add additional resources.

- I have installed visual studio 2022 and added Azure development.
  [image]
- Created a blank template project in **Azure Resource Group**
  [image]
- The project looks like below.
  [image]
- By the below snippet we can deploy individual resources using the Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell.
  [image]

[image]

- Simply navigate to the directory containing your template file and run the appropriate Azure command to deploy the resource. For example, to deploy a `Network Security Group` using Azure CLI

```
az deployment group create --resource-group <resource-group-name> --template-file <template-file-name> --parameters <parameter-file-name>
```

- We can add the latest versions of schema's, Check below.
  [image]
- For more informations please refer this [document.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas)